# My youtube API integration says unathorized what is wrong with my code?

Tags: python, youtube

My code says unauthorized, what am I missing?

When I push the code I get <Response [401]> when I tried creating a json I got error unauthorized.

```
import requests
from secret import api_key
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search"
# channelId= "UCWv7vMbMWH4-V0ZXdmDpPBA"
headers = {
     "Authorization": "Bearer" + api_key
}
params = {
     "part":"snippet",
     "forDeveloper":True,
     "channelId": "UCWv7vMbMWH4-V0ZXdmDpPBA",
     "maxResults": 49,
     "order": "title",
     "q":"python"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers,params=params)

print(response)
```

Comment: Change `"Bearer"` to `"Bearer "`. You need that space.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, I tried it but I am still getting the <Response [401]> I am using a valid API key. Not sure what is causing this.

Comment: By API key you mean something with the format: `AIzaSyXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` and not an `ACCESS_TOKEN` ? If so that is the problem because [as documented](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#forDeveloper) using `Search: list` with `forDeveloper` requires to use [an authorized request](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) using OAuth 2.